# Algorithm Complexity of a Nested While Loop

Tags: algorithm, runtime, discrete-mathematics

So I am having a little bit of trouble on this one because of the variable i.  I am just not sure how to treat it when it is in the second while loop.  For my outer loop I understand that it will run for log_4(n^2) iterations. And for the inner while loop I calculated the number of iterations to be (2n^3 - 3)/i.  I am just struggling on how to put these two together to get the total complexity of this function.  Any input is greatly appreciated!

```
function p(n)
    i = 1;
    while i < n^2 do
        j = 3;
        while j < 2n^3 do
            j = j + i;
        end
        i = 4i;
    end
```

Comment: simply the multiplication of the two values no ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not good at math but I am trying to answer this question.

First let's count from the first iteration:

- i=1:  j is increased about 2n^3 times (the constant can be ignored when analysing complexity)
- i=4:  j is increased about 2n^3/4 times
- i=16: j is increased about 2n^3/16 times.
- ...
- i=n^2: j is increased about 2n^3/(n^2) times.

In total j is increased:
(2n^3)+(2n^3)/4+(2n^3)/16+(2n^3)/64+...+(2n^3)/(n^2) times.
that is:

```
2n^3*(1+1/4+1/16+1/64+1/256+...+1/(n^2))
= 2n^3((1-(1/4)^(log_4(n^2)))/(1-(1/4)))   // sum of geometric progression
= 2n^3 * (1-1/n^2) * 4/3
```

So it's O(n^3).

Comment: Well that's what I managed to get using very different logic.  So hopefully this is right! Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

For inner loop, there exists a situation where i= 1, once in the beginning.
For i = 1, inner loop has about 2n^3 iterations, we can say that complexity is O(n^3) for first run of outer loop.

Note that, since we are trying to calculate complexity, I will get rid of constants and coefficients.

Well, for other values of i, the # of iterations of inner loop is about n^3/i. So while i grows, number of iterations will dramatically decreases. Eventually, it will be n for the last value of i ~= n^2.

So, now, we have a sum like *n^3 + ..... + n* which gives us total complexity.
The number of terms in this summation is log_4(n^2) = 2log_4(n), say log_4(n).

Normally, we know that n^3 + n^2 + n is same as n^3. But the question is can we think of same in this situation? Because in this case, there are more terms and number of terms depend on n. Let's see.

Even if all terms are kind of n^3, the result would be log_4(n)*n^3.
But the value of other terms dropping geometrically in this series, don't keep being n^3. Also log_4(n) is very small value for a big set of numbers people usually work on. Actually one can not simply ignore it, but when we consider together its being a small number and other terms' decreasing dramatically; you can ignore log_4(n) and **we can say that the complexity is O(n^3).**

*It's not an exact mathematical solution, but for ease you we can use such estimating ways if you're sure what we're doing. That's my point and why I'm explaining like this way.*

If you're looking for something more specific, you can say that it's between O(n^3) and O(log_4(n)*n^3).

Also, I had calculated some experimental values for different n values to be sure. You can see how numbers behave in your code, and the relation between # of iterations and n^3. Here are the results:

```
Test #1:
n: 15
n^2: 225, n^3: 3375
...i=1, added 3375 iterations
...i=4, added 843 iterations
...i=16, added 210 iterations
...i=64, added 52 iterations
Total # of iterations for this test case: 4480

Test #2:
n: 56
n^2: 3136, n^3: 175616
...i=1, added 175616 iterations
...i=4, added 43904 iterations
...i=16, added 10976 iterations
...i=64, added 2744 iterations
...i=256, added 686 iterations
...i=1024, added 171 iterations
Total # of iterations for this test case: 234097

Test #3:
n: 136
n^2: 18496, n^3: 2515456
...i=1, added 2515456 iterations
...i=4, added 628864 iterations
...i=16, added 157216 iterations
...i=64, added 39304 iterations
...i=256, added 9826 iterations
...i=1024, added 2456 iterations
...i=4096, added 614 iterations
...i=16384, added 153 iterations
Total # of iterations for this test case: 3353889

Test #4:
n: 678
n^2: 459684, n^3: 311665752
...i=1, added 311665752 iterations
...i=4, added 77916438 iterations
...i=16, added 19479109 iterations
...i=64, added 4869777 iterations
...i=256, added 1217444 iterations
...i=1024, added 304361 iterations
...i=4096, added 76090 iterations
...i=16384, added 19022 iterations
...i=65536, added 4755 iterations
...i=262144, added 1188 iterations
Total # of iterations for this test case: 415553936

Test #5:
n: 2077
n^2: 4313929, n^3: 8960030533
...i=1, added 8960030533 iterations
...i=4, added 2240007633 iterations
...i=16, added 560001908 iterations
...i=64, added 140000477 iterations
...i=256, added 35000119 iterations
...i=1024, added 8750029 iterations
...i=4096, added 2187507 iterations
...i=16384, added 546876 iterations
...i=65536, added 136719 iterations
...i=262144, added 34179 iterations
...i=1048576, added 8544 iterations
...i=4194304, added 2136 iterations
Total # of iterations for this test case: 11946706660

Test #6:
n: 5601
n^2: 31371201, n^3: 175710096801
...i=1, added 175710096801 iterations
...i=4, added 43927524200 iterations
...i=16, added 10981881050 iterations
...i=64, added 2745470262 iterations
...i=256, added 686367565 iterations
...i=1024, added 171591891 iterations
...i=4096, added 42897972 iterations
...i=16384, added 10724493 iterations
...i=65536, added 2681123 iterations
...i=262144, added 670280 iterations
...i=1048576, added 167570 iterations
...i=4194304, added 41892 iterations
...i=16777216, added 10473 iterations
Total # of iterations for this test case: 234280125572

Test #7:
n: 11980
n^2: 143520400, n^3: 1719374392000
...i=1, added 1719374392000 iterations
...i=4, added 429843598000 iterations
...i=16, added 107460899500 iterations
...i=64, added 26865224875 iterations
...i=256, added 6716306218 iterations
...i=1024, added 1679076554 iterations
...i=4096, added 419769138 iterations
...i=16384, added 104942284 iterations
...i=65536, added 26235571 iterations
...i=262144, added 6558892 iterations
...i=1048576, added 1639723 iterations
...i=4194304, added 409930 iterations
...i=16777216, added 102482 iterations
...i=67108864, added 25620 iterations
Total # of iterations for this test case: 2292499180787
```

Comment: "So, you can ignore log_4(n) and we can say that the complexity is O(n^3)." You say we can **ignore** log_4(n), which it's not appropriate. O(log_4(n)*n^3) is very different with O(n^3). And here the exact upper bound is O(n^3). And it's **not** because "log_4(n) is very small number compared to n^3".

Comment: @initrdmk Yeah I know you log_4(n) can't be ignored in log_4(n)*n^3 just because it's a small number. It's a function of n and it's effect of result can be very different for different n's. What I meant was being small is just a small contributor to get the idea. My main argument was in the "the value of other terms decreasing geometrically in this series" part. Sorry, I stated in a wrong way and now I edited the text. Thank you for the correction.